# Nodejs and Mongoose error at throw new Error('record not found') statement

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am running Reactjs+Nodejs and Mongodb connection using mongoose middleware. I have an statement for finding the input merchant id exist or not. If merchant id exists the code works fine but when merchant id not found i am trying to send the error text to react js. the control failed in Nodesjs while throwing the error at statement throw new Error('record not found').

Please find my code below.

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const Merchant = require('../models/merchant')

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const merchantid = await Merchant.findOne({merchantid: req.body.merchantid  }) // grab user from database
        if (!merchantid) {
            throw new Error('record not found')
        }
        req.merchantid = merchantid
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(401).send(e)
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

Please find error message i am getting at line number 8(throw new Error('record not found')).

```
Error: record not found
    at auth (C:\Users\Poorna\Desktop\New_folder\Projects\react\React_new_App\temple_receipt_app\server\middleware\auth.js:8:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: when you have a throw statement this is what is expected to happen. you want a return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is how throw works.  you want to return to the calling system something like this

change

```
    throw new Error('record not found')
```

to

```
    res.status(404)
```